# copying the dataframe accessor when using pd.df.copy()

Tags: python, pandas

Hi so I created a custom accessor for my dataframe, its to make the output formatting easier when outputing html or excel.

```
import pandas as pd

@pd.api.register_dataframe_accessor("css_formatting")
class DataFrameFormatsAccessor(object):
   def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
      self._obj = pandas_obj
      idx = self._obj.index
      col = self._obj.columns
      self.background_color = pd.DataFrame("white", index=idx,columns=col)
   @property
   def background_color(self):
      return self._background_color
```

I then try something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
>>> df
  A B
0 1 4
1 2 5
2 3 6
>>> df.css_formatting.background_color
      A     B
0 white white
1 white white
2 white white
>>> df.css_formattig.background_color.iloc[0,0] = 'red'
>>>df.css_formatting.background_color
      A     B
0   red white
1 white white
2 white white
>>> df2 = df.copy()
>>> df2.css_formatting
      A     B
0 white white
1 white white
2 white white
```

Now I think I understand why this is happening. Every time a new dataframe is created, and the `css_formatting` accessor is initialized, will make the `background_colors` a dataframe of equal size with the value `white` eveything.

My question is, how do I set it up so that `df.copy()` also copies the `css_formatting` accessor. Or is there a different thing I have to try?

edit: To add more,

I've try adding

```
@staticmethod
def copy_formatting(self,other):
   self.background_color = other.css_formatting.background_color
   return
```

And then try the following, after doing what I did in original OP

```
df2.css_formatting.copy_formatting(df2,df)
```

and I get a warning that `Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name`. It also doesn't do what I want.

2nd Edit:

I made a booboo on that static method

```
@staticmethod
def copy_formatting(self,other):
   self.css_formatting.background_color = other.css_formatting.background_color
   return
```

With that being said I'd happily take alternatives that anyone suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a copy method in the accessor class.  Not sure if this has implications, but it works for your use case.  I'm Canadian, so I'm changing color to colour, and shortening the accessor name to 'css':

```
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("css")
class DataFrameFormatsAccessor(object):
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
       self._obj = pandas_obj
       self._background_colour = pd.DataFrame("white", 
                                              index=self._obj.index,
                                              columns=self._obj.columns)

    def copy(self):
        return self._obj

    @property
    def background_colour(self):
       return self._background_colour

    @background_colour.setter
    def background_colour(self, args):
        i, j, colour = args
        self._background_colour.iloc[i, j] = colour
```

Tests:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
print(df.css.background_colour)
       A      B
0  white  white
1  white  white
2  white  white

df.css.background_colour = (1,1,'green')
print(df.css.background_colour)
       A      B
0  white  white
1  white  green
2  white  white

dff = df.css.copy()
print(dff.css.background_colour)
       A      B
0  white  white
1  white  green
2  white  white

dff.css.background_colour = (2,1,'red')
print(dff.css.background_colour)
       A      B
0  white  white
1  white  green
2  white    red
```

Comment: This is interesting. I did not know that copying the pandas object from the accessor would work like that.